# Financial Types

Tags: price-sets, financial-types

I added and enabled a new Financial Type (Advertising). When creating a new price set for it...that financial type is not appearing as an option in the  price set drop down menu.

Any ideas on why it is not appearing even though it is enabled?

Comment: Do you have ACL for financial type enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of two reasons why it is not appearing in price set drop is

1. If you have ACL Financial turned ON (CiviCRM >> Administer >> CiviContribute >> CiviContribute Component Settings) and the user doesn't have permission to perform CRUD on the financial type.
2. If the Financial type has missing 'Income account is' with the financial account. CiviCRM >> Administer >> CiviContribute >> Financial Types. Click **Accounts** on besides the Advertising financial types. If the 'Income account is' is missing than add one.

Thanks

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

I’ve have run into this as well. Try clear caches (possibly twice).